# pandas: what is the fastest way to update a dataframe with values contained in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the following code to update values in the 'user_mmr' column of a dataframe with values in a dictionary called 'user_dict'.

```py
for user_id, user_value in user_dict.items():
    df.loc[df['user_id'] == user_id, 'user_mmr'] = user_value._mmr_object.mu
```

With a large dataset of around 4 million rows, this is very slow.

Is there a faster way to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: `df["user_mmr"]=df["user_id"].map(user_dict)`?

Comment: thanks, this solve the problem!